# Selecting whole subarrays given a multidimensional index

Tags: python, numpy

**Note**: I am 99.9999% sure this must be a duplicate, but for all my searches I can't seem to find the right terms to describe my issue, so please excuse me in advance if this is an obvious duplicate of something.

I have an array of points with shape `[4,2,2]`, where I want to select only one of the values on the second dimension, based on some criteria (irrelevant for the issue, but imagine it's the argmin of the distance between the points and some references).

Say, for example, I have the following arrays:

```py
import numpy as np
points = np.array([[[11.1,  11.2],
                    [12.1,  12.2]],

                   [[21.1, 21.2],
                    [22.1, 22.2]],

                   [[31.1, 31.2],
                    [32.1, 32.2]],

                   [[41.1, 41.2],
                    [42.1, 42.2]]])

indices = np.array([1, 0, 0, 1])
```

The result I'd like is similar to this:

```py
selected_points = []
for pt, idx in zip(points, indices):
  selected_points.append(pt[idx, :])
selected_points = np.asarray(selected_points)
```

which results in

```py
array([[11.1, 11.2],
       [22.1, 22.2],
       [32.1, 32.2],
       [41.1, 41.2]])
```

I want to get rid of the for loop, by using proper indexing. However, all combinations of indices I tried do not work as expected (I get duplicated elements and wrong shapes).

What is the correct "fancy index" to use to obtain the same result, without having to loop over the array?

Comment: Just use `points[np.arange(len(indices)), indices]`.

Comment: Try and use this:  indices = np.array([1, 0, 0, 1])

list_=[]
for key, idx in enumerate(indices):
 list_.append(points[key][idx])
print(np.array(list_))